# Would it be possible to use Apple’s Face ID technology for an app

Tags: ios, face-recognition

Let’s say I want to create a door lock with face recognition. And in order to unlock the door the lock app on my phone has to recognize my face. Would it be possible to use Apple's Face ID for authentication?

Comment: Yes, you can use LocalAuthentication framework to initiate FaceID (if the device supports the FaceID) and authenticate and send that result to your lock to unlock or lock the door.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the LocalAuthentication framework to initiate FaceID (if the device supports the FaceID) and authenticate then use that result.

```
public func loginWithLocalAuthentication(isLoggedIn : @escaping ((Bool)->Void))
{
    let reason = "Log in to your account"
    let context = LAContext()
    context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: reason ) { success, error in
        if success {
            // Move to the main thread because a state update triggers UI changes.
            isLoggedIn(true)

        } else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Failed to authenticate")
            isLoggedIn(false)
        }
    }
}
```